# Symfony compare the value in the session and the value sent by the form

Tags: forms, symfony, session

I generate a random code and then save it in the session.
The user has an input and a "validate" button.
The goal is that the value sent by the user is equal to the value generated in session

I save the code in the session

```
    //Get session
    $session = $request->getSession();
    //Set random code in session
    $session->set("code", $code);

    dump($session->get('code'));
```

I create the form

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ValidCodeType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if ($form["code"]->getData() === $session->get('code')){
            echo "OK";
        }else {
            echo "FAILED";
        }
    }
```

When I get to the page a code is generated (wnt) (and when I reload the page)
The "null" corespond to the value sent by the form

```
dump($form["code"]->getData());
```

[image: La pe]

I submit the form. The value sent is good but a new code has been generated

[image: la pe]

Return FAILED

The code I'm sending is exactly the one that's generated, it should return "OK" to me.

Any ideas? Thank you

Symfony 4

Comment: What's the exact problem? Where should something work different?

Comment: The code I'm sending is exactly the one that's generated, it should return "OK" to me.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe checking for the type of `$form["code"]->getData()` and `$session->get('code')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a guess here but I suspect you are generating your code and setting it on every request before the form is processed.  Hence it changes when the form is posted.  If this is indeed the problem then just move the code past the $form->isValid block.

```
class MyController {
  function myAction() {
    $form = $this->createForm(ValidCodeType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if ($form["code"]->getData() === $session->get('code')){
            echo "OK";
        }else {
            echo "FAILED";
        }
    }
    $code = some_random_code();
    $request->getSession()->set("code", $code);
```

By the way, you seem to be duplicating [Symfony's csrf functionality](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html).

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Cerad